# Is there an XCTFail() equivalent in Quick-Nimble framework?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, quick-nimble

For a particular case, I need to generate failure of test case unconditionally in [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick)-[Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) framework. How do I do this?
An equivalent of `XCTFail("Expecting to get failure callback")` would be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It's part of Nimble, and it's called `fail`.

```
fail("Expecting to get failure callback")
```

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/blob/d0bea4ff70428c0fb30d26c8c1fa2500cd4570ff/Sources/Nimble/DSL.swift#L21-L35).